# What goes in the ssh_keys > key_data argument in a Terraform template

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, ssh-keys, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have a template to deploy a Linux VM in Azure and am trying to use SSH keys for authentication.  When using the "ssh_keys" argument, what goes in the "key_data" sub argument?  I am sure it is something to do with my public key, I am just not sure what exactly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `key_data` is your public key. Your understanding is right.

See this [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/terraform-create-complete-vm).

```
os_profile_linux_config {
    disable_password_authentication = true
    ssh_keys {
        path     = "/home/<user>/.ssh/authorized_keys"
        key_data = "ssh-rsa AAAAB3Nz{snip}hwhqT9h"
    }
}
```

`key_data` value is like `ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDVVucKplaLrdLQZZuESOL8/C07QMheKksR99jBJRyHFqjourKbn6LFvVqwr3ZwxTiCKGarDKzGU3rMwR3itzS3SpJ5pgskbYS+yQsjy//YMVgNNUIvAroQdA9XCYEBBHm/9zGJAWakclGScFW2QaNnJIZlTmaXKyWxAOymIYzS2KsLhqiJDaP5j0j73IARNVgd2gFrxq3U7pnaYKYbPkhEQtPz6V2tXrYgu/M/rEW/Ibit94Z/w/+GHe44IviuXwjLez7Hu24jVx95hsza0AMfnWoPfsk76IEOABvTkJ6sXKfF1DkvPNw/5od/97Mk8eQHmWQLt9rFqiF/r1YrecZN root@shui`

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  How does that get generated?  I generated a key pair using PUTTY and my public key does not have an email at the end...it has rsa-key-<date_generated>.

Comment: You could ssh a Linux VM using putty and use command `ssh-keygen` to generate a pair of key. `root@shui` `root` is generate user and `shui` is hostname. In fact, you could change them.

Comment: You also check this [link](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/creating-ssh-keys-776639788.html). You don't need add `-C "your_email@example.com"`, `ssh-keygen` is enough.

Comment: Hi, please let me know if you need more future help.